# Read outlook emails c# without opening outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, email-attachments

In c#, I am trying to watch for a particular email, then once I receive it, grab attachment and do something with it.  I've done all this before BUT with outlook OPEN.  I want to somehow do this without opening.

To access email in the past I used interop.outlook

Any ideas or things I should look into?

Thanks!!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Is this for an exchange account, or SMTP?

Comment: I had it working using the library Microsoft.interop.outlook.  Which works just fine IF outlook is opened.  This is for my work outlook email, which will only be accessed from inside the company.  I don't know the diff between exch or smto

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, just the right topic or library to research myself

Comment: @solarissf -- Unfortunately, questions like that are off topic for SO.

Comment: out of curiosity.. why is that?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: If interop does work why does it matter if it requires an outlook process to run?

Comment: only because outlook has to be opened.  no worries, I'll work with this or use EWS.

Comment: Be aware EWS is for systems that use Exchange Server, if you don't know thats the case find out before trying anything.

Comment: thanks... I'm not sure, I'll look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to use the EWS Api.

Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx)